# Converting from Numpy Array to PyTorch Tensor

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor, float32

Since Numpy array is Float64 by default. How do I convert to PyTorch tensor to give a FLoat32 type and not 64?

I tried `torch.from_numpy` and it gave a Float64 type.

Comment: `torch.from_numpy(arr).type(torch.FloatTensor)`

Comment: Many thanks, this solved it

Comment: Or you can call `float`: `torch.from_numpy(x).float()`